# Unable to login and share on facebook within TabHost

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK version 3.5.2 in my project. I am having a TabHost with three tabs, and I am Using Facebook Share on one of them. I am using WebDialog for sharing, But when I click on the Share Button, It just open a blank activity and closed itself after 2-3 second.

**Here is the Activity Code in which Facebook Share is used**

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {



    Session.openActiveSession(More.this.getParent(), true,
            new Session.StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    if (session.isOpened()
                            && !session.getPermissions().contains(
                                    "publish_actions")) {
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(
                                More.this.getParent(), "publish_actions"));
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        /*
                         * params.putString("name", titleString);
                         * params.putString("caption", addressString);
                         * params.putString("description",
                         * descriptionString);
                         */
                        params.putString("caption", msgString);
                        // params.putString("link", linkString);

                        params.putString("picture",
                                "live_image_path/logo.jpg");

                        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                                More.this.getParent(), Session
                                        .getActiveSession(), params))
                                .setOnCompleteListener(
                                        new OnCompleteListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(
                                                    Bundle values,
                                                    FacebookException error) {
                                                if (error == null) {
                                                    // When the story is
                                                    // posted, echo the
                                                    // success
                                                    // and the post Id.
                                                    final String postId = values
                                                            .getString("post_id");
                                                    if (postId != null) {

                                                        /*
                                                         * Toast.makeText(
                                                         * More.this,
                                                         * "Posted story, id: "
                                                         * + postId,
                                                         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                                         * ) .show();
                                                         */

                                                    } else {
                                                        // User clicked the
                                                        // Cancel button
                                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                                More.this,
                                                                "Publish cancelled",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                                .show();
                                                    }
                                                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                                    // User clicked the "x"
                                                    // button
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            More.this
                                                                    .getParent(),
                                                            "Publish cancelled",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                            .show();
                                                } else {
                                                    // Generic, ex: network
                                                    // error
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            More.this
                                                                    .getParent(),
                                                            "Error posting story",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                            .show();
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }).build();
                        feedDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```